# Null reference with @Html.Hidden in MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two views, Create and Edit. Both are having a hidden field called `ModelType` to use it in my model binder to bind all the subclasses also.

This hidden field is working fine in Edit view, but not in Create view. I am getting a `null reference exception` at line:

```
@Html.Hidden("ModelType" , Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

in Create view.

What is wrong here?

Edit.cshtml

```
@using PartyBiz.Models.Objects
@model Organization

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Organization", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Organization</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.C, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C) 
    </div> <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.N)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.N, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.N)
    </div> <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.D)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.D, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.D)
    </div> 
    <br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.PID)
        @Html.Hidden("ModelType" , Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />

</fieldset>
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@using PartyBiz.Models.Objects
@model Organization

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Organization", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create a New Organization</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.C, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C) 
    </div> <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.N)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.N, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.N)
    </div> <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.D)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.D, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.D)
    </div> 
    <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        @Html.Hidden("ModelType" , Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)

</fieldset>
}
```

model binder

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix("ModelType"))
        {
            //get the model type
            var typeName = (string)bindingContext
                .ValueProvider
                .GetValue("ModelType")
                .ConvertTo(typeof(string));
            var modelType = Type.GetType(typeName);

            //tell the binder to use it
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata =
                ModelMetadataProviders
                .Current
                .GetMetadataForType(null, modelType);
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your controller action which shows the create view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't pass any value as your model in the `Create` method. Your create method probably looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will result in the `Model` property being `null` in the Razor template. To work around this you can pass in a default instance of your model class:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Organization());
}
```

Comment: Ohh yes!! Is there a permanent solution for this? Can I use my factories in my controllers to written some brand new organization?just asking if this is good practice to access factories in controllers...

Comment: Yes you could use your factories if you want to, there is no harm in that.

Comment: if you **@Html.TextBoxFor()** which a bound helper, you need to pass an instance of the viewmodel you are using...